# How to create session using repository in android?

Tags: android

How to create session in android to pass sensitive data(password, login, etc) between activities/fragments? I don't want to save this data in local storage. If application session end, data should be erased.

Comment: what do you mean by session? Does the session end when you close the app? or does it end when the user logs out?

Comment: Session should end app close or user log out.